# Error 0x80070021 IIS windows 8

Tags: iis

I'm trying to deploy web pages on IIS. When I try to browse site I got such mistake:

> This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens
>   when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by
>   default (`overrideModeDefault="Deny"`), or set explicitly by a location
>   tag with `overrideMode="Deny"` or the legacy `allowOverride="false"`.

Section in my config file:

```
 <security>
        <authentication>
            <basicAuthentication enabled="false" />
        </authentication>
 </security>
```

May anybody help me to "unlock" parent section (as far as I understand).

Comment: Why do you need to touch authentication in web.config? It is supposed to be controlled by IIS and usually managed via IIS Manager.

Comment: A tried to delete section from config file. Now i'm trying to resolve problem with autentification

Answer (score 0):

You may need to allow feature delegation.

IIS Manager -> Feature Delegation

Select "Authentication - Basic" and change it to Read/Write.

By default it is ReadOnly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem when I tried to deploy ASP.NET pages on IIS. (To be honest don´t know if exactly the same - I am using Windows 10 now, but got same kind of message).

At first it seamed complicated to fix  but found out that had a really easy solution.

I Just needed to reinstal IIS at the Control Painel - but with ASP option enabled (I enabled all of the resources for development of applications).

And at the Website (basic) configuration had to select .NET v4.5 Classic.

Answer (score -1):

Error 500.19 and file execution issues and locked on IIS 8

To resolve it I had to execute in cmd:

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/handlers
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd unlock config -section:system.webServer/modules